# exact position not getting fetched on random checkbox selection in listview,shows indexoutofboundsexception

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, indexoutofboundsexception, android-checkbox

I have a listview with a textview and a checkbox which gets populated from an arraylist getting data from web service.It works fine.Now when I check on a particular checkbox position in the list is getting fetched if I check linearly from top to bottom.**However if I check any checkbox randomly** in the list the exact position of the checkbox is not fetched and it shows **indexoutofbounds** exception.I have tried both array adapter and base adapter.please help me.

Base Adapter

```
public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<FtpTable> ftpTables) {

    //Common.selectedFtpTable=null;
     this.mContext= context;
    this.ftpTables = ftpTables;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

}

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView name_agency;
    CheckBox cb_agency;
    //TextView ime;
    //TextView telefon1;
    //TextView telefon2;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ftpTables.size();
}

@Override
public FtpTable getItem(int position) {
    return ftpTables.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_agencies_row, parent, false);

        holder.name_agency = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_agency);
        holder.cb_agency=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.chk_agency);



        view.setTag(holder);
        holder.cb_agency.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (holder.cb_agency.isChecked()) {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"You have selected:"+ftpTables.get(position).getNewsAgency("newsAgency"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Common.selectedNewsAgencyArray.add(ftpTables.get(position).getNewsAgency("newsAgency"));
                    //Common.selectedFtpTable.add(ftpTables.get(position));
                    //Toast.makeText(mContext,Common.selectedFtpTable.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Common.selectedHostArray.add(ftpTables.get(position).getHostFtp("hostFtp"));
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"SIZE OF HOST ARRAY:"+Common.selectedHostArray.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // Toast.makeText(mContext,"You have added:"+Common.selectedHostArray.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Common.selectedUsernameArray.add(ftpTables.get(position).getUsernameFtp("usernameFtp"));
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"SIZE OF USERNAME ARRAY:"+Common.selectedUsernameArray.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(mContext,"You have added:"+Common.selectedUsernameArray.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Common.selectedPasswordArray.add(ftpTables.get(position).getPasswordFtp("passwordFtp"));
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"SIZE OF PASSWORD ARRAY:"+Common.selectedPasswordArray.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"You have added:"+Common.selectedHostArray.get(position)+","+Common.selectedUsernameArray.get(position)+","+Common.selectedPasswordArray.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"You have unselected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   /*indexToRemove = Common.selectedHostArray.indexOf(ftpTables.get(position).getHostFtp("hostFtp"));
                   Common.selectedHostArray.remove(indexToRemove);
                    Common.selectedNewsAgencyArray.remove(indexToRemove);
                    Common.selectedUsernameArray.remove(indexToRemove);
                    Common.selectedPasswordArray.remove(indexToRemove);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"SIZE OF HOST ARRAY:"+Common.selectedHostArray.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"SIZE OF USERNAME ARRAY:"+Common.selectedUsernameArray.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"SIZE OF PASSWORD ARRAY:"+Common.selectedPasswordArray.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"You have removed:"+Common.selectedHostArray.get(indexToRemove)+","+Common.selectedUsernameArray.get(indexToRemove)+","+Common.selectedPasswordArray.get(indexToRemove),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.name_agency.setText(ftpTables.get(position).getNewsAgency("newsAgency"));
    //holder.telefon1.setText(taxiLists.get(position).getTelefon1("telefon1"));
    //holder.telefon2.setText(taxiLists.get(position).getTelefon2("telefon2"));


    return view;
}
```

Array Adapter

```
public class AgencyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FtpTable> {
    public List<FtpTable> ftpTables = null;
    int indexToRemove=-1;
    Context mContext;
    int CheckValue;

    public AgencyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FtpTable> tables,int CheckValue) {
        super(context, 0, tables);
        this.mContext= context;
        this.ftpTables = tables;
        this.CheckValue=CheckValue;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        //Common.position=position;
        FtpTable ftpTable = getItem(position);
        //convertView.setTag(ftpTable);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        //if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_agencies_row, parent, false);

            final TextView name_agency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_agency);
            final CheckBox cb_agency = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_agency);
            convertView.setTag(ftpTable);
            cb_agency.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    if (cb_agency.isChecked()) {

                    /*if (CheckValue == 0) {
                        CheckValue = 1;
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,String.valueOf(CheckValue),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                        //cb_agency.setChecked(true);
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "You have selected:" + ftpTables.get(position).getNewsAgency("newsAgency"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Common.selectedNewsAgencyArray.add(ftpTables.get(position).getNewsAgency("newsAgency"));
                        //Common.selectedFtpTable.add(ftpTables.get(position));
                        //Toast.makeText(mContext,Common.selectedFtpTable.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Common.selectedHostArray.add(ftpTables.get(position).getHostFtp("hostFtp"));
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SIZE OF HOST ARRAY:" + Common.selectedHostArray.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Toast.makeText(mContext,"You have added:"+Common.selectedHostArray.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Common.selectedUsernameArray.add(ftpTables.get(position).getUsernameFtp("usernameFtp"));
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SIZE OF USERNAME ARRAY:" + Common.selectedUsernameArray.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Toast.makeText(mContext,"You have added:"+Common.selectedUsernameArray.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Common.selectedPasswordArray.add(ftpTables.get(position).getPasswordFtp("passwordFtp"));
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SIZE OF PASSWORD ARRAY:" + Common.selectedPasswordArray.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "You have added:" + Common.selectedHostArray.get(position) + "," + Common.selectedUsernameArray.get(position) + "," + Common.selectedPasswordArray.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //CheckValue=0;
                    } else {
                        //cb_agency.setChecked(false);
                        //Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(CheckValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "You have unselected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Toast.makeText(mContext,CheckValue,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   /*indexToRemove = Common.selectedHostArray.indexOf(ftpTables.get(position).getHostFtp("hostFtp"));
                   Common.selectedHostArray.remove(indexToRemove);
                    Common.selectedNewsAgencyArray.remove(indexToRemove);
                    Common.selectedUsernameArray.remove(indexToRemove);
                    Common.selectedPasswordArray.remove(indexToRemove);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"SIZE OF HOST ARRAY:"+Common.selectedHostArray.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"SIZE OF USERNAME ARRAY:"+Common.selectedUsernameArray.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"SIZE OF PASSWORD ARRAY:"+Common.selectedPasswordArray.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"You have removed:"+Common.selectedHostArray.get(indexToRemove)+","+Common.selectedUsernameArray.get(indexToRemove)+","+Common.selectedPasswordArray.get(indexToRemove),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                    }
                }
            });
            name_agency.setText(ftpTables.get(position).getNewsAgency("newsAgency"));
            //holder.telefon1.setText(taxiLists.get(position).getTelefon1("telefon1"));
            //holder.telefon2.setText(taxiLists.get(position).getTelefon2("telefon2"));
            // Lookup view for data population
            //TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            //TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHome);
            // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
            //tvName.setText(user.name);
            //tvHome.setText(user.hometown);
            // Return the completed view to render on screen

            return convertView;
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make position variable final, get the object of FtpTable by using tag `cb_agency.setTag(ftpTable);` then fetch the object in `setOnCheckedChangeListener` by using `compoundButton.getTag()`.

```
cb_agency.setTag(ftpTable);
cb_agency.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                FtpTable ftp = (FtpTable) compoundButton.getTag();
                //now you don't need position variable here.
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "You have selected:" + ftp.getNewsAgency("newsAgency"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried two adapters base adapter and array adapter and both showed the same exception.I have edited the question with the base adapter code.as far as final keyword is concerned if I dont make the keyword final it is not getting fetched in onCheckChanged.what do I do?

Comment: I told you in my answer, you can get object using tag you don't need position.

Comment: so wherever I am using position in onCheckChanged should I edit it with cb_agency,getTag()?can u pls edit my code and post it for me how to do it?

Comment: I have edited my answer. you can replace `ftpTables.get(position)` with `ftp`. and don't forget to remove final from position variable.

Comment: Thanks 100000 times.You made my day.I was pissed off with this issue for a number of  days.Thanks a lot again

Comment: see [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: dumb question divy but i am not able to locate the upvote triangle mentioned in the link.is it on this page only?